# How to create a data structure for objects that are technically the same thing but doesn't always share the same attributes?

Tags: mysql, data-structures, go-gorm, grpc-go

I know that title was a mouthful, but I hope that summarizes my question well. So I want to represent some sensors that vary in the fields they have. Some of them share fields, other have a field that only they have. Now, I want to get those infos in a good way. I thought of some hacky way to do it, but it involves hardcoding the table name and passing that to the client as well. Here's what my sensor info tables looks like:

```
Sensor1
    -Info1
    -Info2
    -Info3
Sensor2
    -Info4
    -Info5
    -Info6
    -Info7
Sensor3
    -Info8
Sensor4
    -Info9
    -Info10
    -Info11
Sensor5
    -Info12
    -Info13
    -Info14
    -Info15
Sensor6
    -Info15
    -Info14
    -Info18
    -Info9
    -Info10
    -Info11
    -Info12
```

I could think of some solutions to this, but everything would just be messy and ugly.

Here's what my current hacks looks like:

```
ginGine.GET("/sensors", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    //[table name][display name]
    sensorLst := map[string]string{
        "sensor_1_table_name": "Sensor 1",
        "sensor_2_table_name": "Sensor 2",
        "sensor_3_table_name": "Sensor 3",
        "sensor_4_table_name": "Sensor 4",
        "sensor_5_table_name": "Sensor 5",
        "sensor_6_table_name": "Sensor 6",
    }

    type Record struct {
        ID string
    }

    //[table name][info array]
    respMap := make(map[string][]map[string]string)
    for k, v := range sensorLst {
        recs := []Record{}
        cmmHelpers.GetDB().Raw(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT id FROM %s", k)).Find(&recs)

        for _, el := range recs {
            //[record id][display name]
            info := map[string]string{}

            //populate info map
            info["id"] = el.ID
            info["table_name"] = k
            info["display_name"] = v
            //get the existing info list/map associated with the table name key of sensorLst
            innerMap := respMap[k]

            //add the new info to innerMap
            innerMap = append(innerMap, info)
            //replace the old innerMap with the updated one
            respMap[k] = innerMap
        }
    }

    //convert map to byte[]
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(respMap)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshaling JSON:", err)
        return
    }

    ctx.Data(200, "application/json; charset=utf-8", []byte(jsonData))
})
```

UPDATE:

I thought of a possible solution and want to get some opinion about it. What if I made a monolith `Sensor` model which has all the possible fields. Then on the `gin` parts, I'll use the old small models for the parts that need them. Then on saving, I'll "transfer" the data those small models contains to the monolith model, so I'll have a sensor table. I tried looking at interfaces, but it doesn't work like most object oriented language. (Just realized that solution is still messy, but at least it's not a pig pen I guess that would involve more hacky ways to retrieve it later)

Comment: How is your info used? it is only saved/stored/retrieved, or it is used by some another way (find max value, get average, filter by range, etc.)? There are at least 3 schemes: sparse table (each info have its own column, non-used infos for particular sensor type stores NULL), EAV scheme (separate table which stores sensorID, infoID and value), serialized scheme (all infos are stored one column in JSON format or similar).

Comment: Those infos are kind of a way to set some configuration related to the sensors, like acceptable min and max values. Sparse table seems like one of the option I have mind, but pretty messy as each table needs to have all the possible fields. For EAV, our "smart friend" did suggest that, but is more messy than sparse table. All those info as accompanied by 3 more fields, so I don't like to add more fields if possible. On serialized scheme, IIUC, I have like a single field that gets a JSON that contains all the fields that a table needs? Can you share some samples of those?

Comment: *Can you share some samples of those?* ```CREATE TABLE sensors (id INT, info JSON);``` then ```INSERT INTO sensors VALUES (1, '{"info1":12, "info2":"qwe", "info3":34}'), (2, '{"info2":"asd", "info3":999, "info4":444, "info7":"2023-01-01"}');```

Comment: I meant like example for all those option. But thanks for that anyway. Yep, I figured that that's how it would be done. Problem is I'm using gRPC, gin and gorm to help with stuff so I have to do some extra stuff to implement that.

Comment: *Any known disadvantage with that approach?* Additional work when you need to retrieve the value for separate info which makes those type of queries slow. For example, when you need to retrieve only the sensors where the number in info5 is 3 or 4 and the date in info12 is within last week - the server must parse all JSON values, for all rows, retrieve separate infos then test their values.

Comment: Yeah, also after some more thinking, I don't think `gorm` would allow me to have a JSON key that isn't backed by an actual field, because `gorm` and `gin` uses the `gorm.Model` to check the validity of the data passed to the API and on saving to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a solution to this, which is basically what I had in my update. I made a monolith Sensor model then used the smaller ones for data structure validation with `gin` to ensure that only the fields necessary for a sensor type is required.

Here's what the monolith looks like:

```
type Sensor struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;" json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Type SensorType `json:"type"`
    Info1 float32 `json:"info_1"`
    Info2 float32 `json:"info_2"`
    ...
    ...
    InfoN float32 `json:"info_n"`
}
```

Then for the validation models, they look like this:

```
type Sensor1 struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID string `gorm:"primarykey; size:40;" json:"id"`
    Name string
    Info1 *float32 `gorm:"not null" json:"info_1" binding:"required"`
    Info2 *float32 `gorm:"not null" json:"info_2" binding:"required"`
    ...
}
```

Notice that pointer for the variable type and `binding:"required"`, they are both necessary for `gin` to really require them.

Then the actual code looks like this:

//client side

```
ginGine.POST("/sensor_1", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var sensor_1 models.Sensor1

    err := ctx.ShouldBind(&sensor_1)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
}
```

//server side

```
func (*Sensor1Server) CreateSensor1(ctx context.Context, req *pb.CreateSensor1Request) (*pb.CreateSensor1Response, error) {
    fmt.Printf("Create Sensor1 Timestamp: %v\n", time.Now())

    sensor_1 := req.GetSensor1()
    sensor_1.Id = uuid.New().String()

    data := models.Sensor{
        ID:    sensor_1.GetId(),
        Name:  sensor_1.GetName(),
        Type:  models.SENSOR1,
        Info1: sensor_1.GetInfo1(),
        Info2: sensor_1.GetInfo2(),
        ...
        ...
    }

    res := cmmHelpers.GetDB().Create(&data)
    ...
    ...
}
```